# git add option like -a for git commit

Tags: git, rebase

During a long rebase (say, for an integration branch with lots of commits to the main development branch), I frequently have to `git add` all of the files with conflicts that I've resolved.

Recently I tried `git add -all` thinking it would be like `git commit -a` but no luck: it also added any untracked files I happened to have.

I need to add all tracked files that were modified during the (partial) rebase, before using `git rebase --continue`.  Is there a simple way to get the list of files that would be added by `git commit -a`?  Then I could use this list at the end of `git add`.

Comment: Not sure it fits your need and context, but take a look at `git add -u`, doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--u).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git add -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--u) (short for `--update`):

> Update the index just where it *already has an entry matching* `<pathspec>`. This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files. (emphasis mine)

"Update the index" is Git parlance for "stage the changes". I tried it in a new repo and conflicting files are staged too, so it would fit your use case.